# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-dom

Am new to react JS I have encountered an error while pushing data:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined**

```
this.props.clist.forEach(function(company) {
companies.push( <Company company={company} onCompanyDelete={that.handleCompanyRemove} /> );
});
```

complete code :
https://codepen.io/prashanthHarish/pen/jxVWGE (line 49)

example from http://tuts-javascript.appspot.com/reactjs-add-remove-table-row

Comment: Did you try accessing like “that.props”?

Answer (score 0):

you dont have "clist" prop passed to CompanyList component. pass that prop then you can use it

Comment: With demonstration will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

if you see your handelNewRowSubmission function

```
handleNewRowSubmit: function( newcompany ) {
      this.setState( {companylist: this.state.companylist.concat([newcompany])} );
    }
```

you are using concat which will just concat. if you need a list of array then you save the value to some variable and push new value to it and then assign it to companyList state.

```
var compList = [];
compList = this.state.companylist;
compList.push(newcompany);
this.setState({companylist : compList});
```